# What is wrong in my .htaccess code?

Tags: php, .htaccess

**Thank you for reading**

I am trying to get my website working again. I am running it on a webhost in stead of a virtual server. The code below is the .htaccesss I am using currently.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 2 

RewriteRule ^error/(.*)$ error.php?p=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 4 

RewriteRule ^Administratie/backup/(.*)$ admin.php?    p=dash&pagina=backup&table=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 5 

RewriteRule ^Administratie/chatlogs_popup/(.*)$ admin.php?    p=chatlogs_popup&speler=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 6 

RewriteRule ^Administratie/berichtenbalk/verwijder/(.*)$ admin.php?p=dash&pagina=berichtenbalk&id=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 7 

RewriteRule ^Administratie/(.*)$ admin.php?p=dash&pagina=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 8 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 9 

RewriteRule ^team/(.*)$ index.php?p=team&staff=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 10 

RewriteRule ^forum/categorie/(.*)/topic/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=forum&id=$1&topic=$2 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 11 

RewriteRule ^forum/categorie/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=forum&id=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 12 

RewriteRule ^helptool/ticket/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=helptool&id=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 13 

RewriteRule ^helptool/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=helptool&pagina=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 14 

RewriteRule ^groep_overzicht/favoriet/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=groep_overzicht&favo=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 15 

RewriteRule ^groep_overzicht/wordlid/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=groep_overzicht&lid=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 16 

RewriteRule ^bank/(.*)$ index.php?p=bank&rekening=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 17 

RewriteRule ^nieuws/(.*)/p/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=nieuws&id=$1&pagina=$2 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 18 

RewriteRule ^nieuws/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=nieuws&id=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 19 

RewriteRule ^pagina/(.*)/quote/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=pagina&naam=$1&quote=$2 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 20 

RewriteRule ^pagina/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=pagina&naam=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 21 

RewriteRule ^meldingen/id/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=meldingen&extra=id&id=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 22 

RewriteRule ^minimail/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=minimail&extra=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 23 

RewriteRule ^client/id/(.*)$ index.php?p=client&roomid=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 24 

RewriteRule ^groups/(.*)/id$ ./index.php?p=groep&id=$1 []

#RULE IMPORTED RULE 25 

RewriteRule ^botsbeheer/(.*)$ ./index.php?p=botsbeheer&id=$1 []

</IfModule>
```

It results in an Internal Server Error. I don't know how I can resolve this. Is anybody able to help me with this?

Comment: In what case does it result in an internal Server Error?

Comment: All cases. - Not existing pages; Existing pages; Pages in different directories.

Comment: I see your square brackets are empty. Can you remove them and test OR just put the right config in the brackets and test again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, remove brackets `[]` at the end of lines and spaces before `?` in rule 4. May be, result will be correct :)